# How to write to a file and save it to another machine on same network using python?

Tags: python

In this script I am taking the temperature from a DHT11 sensor and parsing the data that another script can read. Everything works except for writing the file to another pc using the path I placed in the f = open part of the script below. Everything works great except that the file doesn't get written or saved.

Any Help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import sys
import time
import dht11
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#define GPIO 14 as DHT11 data pin
Temp_sensor=14

def main():
    # Main program block
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)       # Use BCM GPIO numbers
    instance = dht11.DHT11(pin = Temp_sensor)

    while True: 
        #get DHT11 sensor value
        result = instance.read()
        temp = '{:.0f}'.format(result.temperature * 1.8 + 32)+"°"
        # The path to send the txt file to and save is /10.1.1.28/c$/Temperature_RETR/kvoa_temp.txt
        if result.is_valid():
            print temp
            f = open('\\10.1.1.28\c$\Temperature_RETR\new_temp.txt','w')
            #f = open('/home/pi/Desktop/new_temp.txt','w')
            y = temp
            z = str(y)
            f.write(z)
            f.close() 
            time.sleep(60) # 60 second delay

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: I think you need to use forward slash, not backslashes: `//10.1.1.28/c/...`. You could also build the path with `os.path.join()`.

Comment: Other options: `r'\\10.1.1.28\c$\Temperature_RETR\new_temp.txt'`, `'\\\\10.1.1.28\\c$\\Temperature_RETR\\new_temp.txt'`

Comment: Python uses the backslash to escape into control characters. For instance `\n` is a new line. This should have failed in the open.